# How to get the selected value of a fropdownList and send it to a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this bit of code in one of my views.

Instead of this hardcoded for testing,

selectedProduct=" + "Bonds"

I need 
selectedProduct=" +  SelectedValueFromTheDropDownList

How can I get the selected value?
Tks in advance

```
<div class="Left Width50Perc" style="display: inline">
    <select id="searchForBondsSelect">
         <option value="Bonds">Bonds</option>
         <option value="Stocks">Stocks</option>
         <option value="Funds">Funds</option>
         <option value="ETFS">ETFs</option>
     </select>
</div>

<div class="Right  Width50Perc">
    <div class="Left FilterTooltip" style="display: inline">
        @CommonHelpers.AutoCompleteTextBox("/st/searchlist?partialString={0}**&selectedProduct=" +  "Bonds"**, InputClass: "TextBox2 Data10 AutoCompleteTextBox", Watermark: "Enter a value")
    </div>
</div>*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed with the help of Thereader.

I tried a different approach with new code which was not working.

```
<div class="Left Width50Perc" style="display: inline">
    <select id="searchForBondsSelect" class="selectedValue">
        <option value="Bonds">Bonds</option>
        <option value="Stocks">Stocks</option>
        <option value="Funds">Funds</option>
        <option value="ETFS">ETFs</option>
    </select>
 </div>

<script>
    $(".selectedValue").select(
        {
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(".selectedValue").val(ui.select.val);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/searchtool/st/GetProductType",
                    data: { productType: ui.select.val },
                    async: true,
                    type: "POST",

                })
            }
        });
</script>
```

Then the TheReader suggested this. Thanks once again.

```
<script>

    $(".selectedValue").change(function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: "/searchtool/st/GetProductType",
             data: { productType: $(this).val() },
             async: true,
             type: "POST",
         })
    });
     </script>
```